# Understanding state-machine for detecting C-style comments

Tags: c, enums, comments

I have understood the entire functionality of this program except the way it handles a nested comment input. The functionality of the State Star is unclear to me. What does `c!='*'` imply?

Suppose the input is `haha /* hello /*world */`, then after the first star if a slash comes, the control shifts to the `PROGRAM` state. however why is it accounting for `c!='*'`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
enum{ /*Enum construct declares states */
    PROGRAM,
    SLASH,
    STAR,
    QUOTE,
    COMMENT,
    LITERAL
}state;

/* If state is quote then its either " or '*/

state = PROGRAM;

for(;;)
{
    int c = getchar();
    int quote = 0 ;

    switch(state) {
    case SLASH:
        /* Program text following a slash */
        if (c == '*') {
            state = COMMENT;
            break;
        }
        putchar('/');
        state = PROGRAM;

    case PROGRAM:
        /*Program Text*/
        if (c == '\''||c == '"') {
            state = QUOTE;
            quote = c;
            putchar(quote);
        }
        else if (c == '/')
            state = SLASH;
        else
            putchar(c);
        break;

    case COMMENT:
        /* Comment */
        if (c == '*')
            state = STAR;
        break;

    case STAR:
        /*Comment following a Star */
        if (c == '/')
            state = PROGRAM;
        else if (c != '*') {
            state = COMMENT;
            putchar(' ');
        }
        break;

    case QUOTE:
        /*Within a quote or a string */
        putchar(c);
        if (c == '\\')
            state = LITERAL;
        else if (c == quote)
            state = PROGRAM;
        break;

    case LITERAL:
        /*Within a literal having /*/
        putchar(c);
        state = QUOTE;
        break;
    }
}

printf("Can it handle this /* I wonder */");
getch();
}
```

Comment: `"/*"[1]` LOL!  Isn't that just `'*'`?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes it is, what failure. Though it's probably just to indicate that they're looking for a `/*` which may be unclear when you seperate the `/` and `*`

Comment: I don't see a `'\*'`, I see a `"/*"[1]`, which is just an ugly (and stupid) `'*'`.

Comment: `if (c == "/*"[1]) {` Is a silly way of saying `if (c == '*') {`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry my bad ! It was c!='*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to cope with input like this:

```
blah /* comment **/ blah
                 ^
```

If you reverted to `COMMENT` at the point I've marked, then you wouldn't be looking for the `/` in order to revert to `PROGRAM`.  You need to stay in `STAR`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in state STAR and you find a STAR, you want to stay in state STAR, in case you're looking at something like `****/`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are in the `COMMENT` state (we've just encountered '/*'), this code will continue looping until it sees a "*".  However, we should only leave the `COMMENT` state if we see '/' after the '*'.  If we don't see a slash, but put ourselves back into the comment state, we are going to skip over cases where the comment ends like '**/', because we wouldn't continue trying to find the '/' in the `STAR` state.  You would revert back to `COMMENT` and look at c=='/' in the next iteration, skipping over what was actually the end of the comment, and then slurp program text until the next '*/'.

Comment: Great Explanation . I got it though . Thanks a lot.